# Adding standalone=no field to XML declaration using XMLStreamWriter

Tags: java, xml, xmlstreamwriter

I'm currently using XMLStreamWriter to parse together an XML document. The only parameters that I'm allowed to pass in are "encoding" and "version", but I would like to have "standalone=no" in the declaration, as well. Here's what my output currently looks like:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
```

How can I make something like this?

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='no'?>
```

Comment: You will need to post the Java code you're using

Comment: You are probably out of luck. The public API does not know about "standalone", and the most recent source I could find for the implementation (Java 6) contains the comment `// what about standalone?`

Answer (score 1):

`XmlStreamWriter` is an interface: it has more than one implementation!

If you install Saxon (any edition), you can create a Serializer using any of the serialization parameters defined in XSLT (for example standalone=yes), and then you can get an `XmlStreamWriter` that writes to this `Serializer` using `Serializer.getXmlStreamWriter()`:

```
Processor p = new Processor(false);
Serializer s = p.newSerializer(System.out);
s.setOutputProperty(Property.STANDALONE, "no");
XmlStreamWriter writer = s.getXmlStreamWriter();
```